# How to return a string from method?

Tags: javascript

I try to send a name and a color to the constructor function below. The method `this.whatAreYou()` should to retrieve these strings when called.

I want to display this on the screen.

I have the following code:

```
function Gadget(name, color) {
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.whatAreYou = function() {
        return 'I am a ' + this.name+ ' ' + this.color;
    };
}

string = Gadget(grass, green);
alert(string);​
```

however the alert is not functioning. How can I achieve my desired behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Gadget isn't a string. It just holds a function returning a string.

As you seem to try to create an instance of the Gadget class, you need to use the `new` operator.

If `grass` and `green` aren't predefined variables but strings, you need to put them between quotes.

Try

```
var g = new Gadget('grass', 'green');
alert(g.whatAreYou());​
```

Comment: thanks alot what about `Gadget.prototype = {
price: 100,
rating: 3,
getInfo: function() {
return 'Rating: ' + this.rating + ', price: ' + this.price;
}
};

var gadget = new Gadget();
var string = gadget.getInfo();
alert(string);
`

Comment: Seems good (hard to read in comments). Using a prototype is a good idea (I suppose you've defined the constructor before as in your question).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create an instance of `Gadget` using the `new` operator.

```
var gadget = new Gadget('grass', 'green');
var string = gadget.whatAreYou();
alert(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function Gadget(name, color) {
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.whatAreYou = function() {
        return 'I am a ' + this.name+ ' ' + this.color;
    };
return this.whatAreYou;
}

string = Gadget(grass, green);
alert(string);​
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a few things wrong, including the parameters passing into gadget are not in quotes.  And you are never invoking whatAreYou().

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function Gadget(name, color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
        this.whatAreYou = function () {
            return 'I am a ' + this.name + ' ' + this.color;
        };
        return whatAreYou();
    }

    alert(Gadget('grass', 'green'));


</script>
```